# how do i validate a postal code such as a canadian one (M3M 2B2) from my array?

Tags: actionscript-3

the array that i have my input for the postal code is called myArray and the box number is 10 so to call it or reference it myArray[10]

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It will be easier for someone to answer if you can provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have it in String format, the standard way to validate it *for correct format* would be a regular expression:

```
var myPostalCodeStr:String = "M2M 2B2";
trace(myPostalCodeStr.match(/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$/) != null);
```

But this only checks that the pattern fits that of a postal code, it does not tell you if the code is one that is actually assigned to a town--if you need that, then you need a complete list of codes from the post office to check against, and you'd need to maintain that to keep it up to date.

Comment: i'd just like to mention that the space in canadian postal codes has become optional over the years.

Comment: Yep, the asterisk in the middle of this regexp generously allows for any amount of spaces between the two halves. You could replace it with {0,1} to allow only no space or one space.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things could be meant by validation.

1. a facial validation (correct format)
2. data validation (is the postal code a legitimate Canada Post code)

Assuming it the latter, you can check the data a couple ways. Find an API (I still haven't found one that I trust for commercial use- that will be around) -or- get the data itself from a place like [greatdata.com](http://greatdata.com) or [melissadata.com](http://melissadata.com).

ps - if the former was intended, check out [stackoverflow-question-4746109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746109/jquery-postal-code-clientvalidate)